# Problem with map(map(string)) in variable

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to use this module for Terraform: [Artifact Registry module](https://github.com/binxio/terraform-google-artifact-registry). I have a variable for Terraform of the following construct.

```
variable "repositories" {
description = "Repositories setup."
type = object({
  owner        = string
  location     = string
  format       = string
  description  = string
  roles        = map(map(string))
  labels       = map(string)
  kms_key_name = string
})
default = {
  activerepo = {
    owner = "eric@xxxxxx"
    location = "asia-east1"
    format = "DOCKER"
    description = "Docker repository"
    roles = [{
      members = "mark@xxxxxx"
      role = "artifactregistry.admin"
      },
    ]
    labels = null
    kms_key_name = null
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` I get the below output:

```
│ Error: Invalid default value for variable
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 59, in variable "repositories":
│   59:   default = {
│   60:     activeops = {
│   61:       owner = "eric@xxxxxxx"
│   62:       location = "asia-east1"
│   63:       format = "DOCKER"
│   64:       description = "Docker repository"
│   65:       roles = [{
│   66:         members = "mark@xxxxxxxx"
│   67:         role = "artifactregistry.admin"
│   68:       },
│   69:       ]
│   70:       labels = null
│   71:       kms_key_name = null
│   72:     }
│   73:   }
│ 
│ This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: attributes
  "description", "format", "kms_key_name", "labels", "location", "owner", and "roles"
  are required.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Eric.

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default value is a **map of objects**, not an object. Also your `roles` is a **list of maps**, not a map of maps. So it should be:

```
variable "repositories" {

  description = "Repositories setup."
  
  type = map(object({
    owner        = string
    location     = string
    format       = string
    description  = string
    roles        = list(map(string))
    labels       = map(string)
    kms_key_name = string
  }))
  
  default = {
    activerepo = {
      owner = "eric@xxxxxx"
      location = "asia-east1"
      format = "DOCKER"
      description = "Docker repository"
      roles = [{
        members = "mark@xxxxxx"
        role = "artifactregistry.admin"
        },
      ]
      labels = null
      kms_key_name = null
      }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to adjust `default` value to the `type` it should be:

```
variable "repositories" {

  description = "Repositories setup."
  
  type = object({
    owner        = string
    location     = string
    format       = string
    description  = string
    roles        = map(map(string))
    labels       = map(string)
    kms_key_name = string
  })
  
  default = {
      owner = "eric@xxxxxx"
      location = "asia-east1"
      format = "DOCKER"
      description = "Docker repository"
      roles = {
          myrole= {          
           members = "mark@xxxxxx"
           role = "artifactregistry.admin"
        }},
      labels = null
      kms_key_name = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but throws the same error.
I think the module does expect a map of maps as that's in the example but I don't know how to reflect that in the roles section..

Comment: @EricV. I updated the answer with the oposite change - update default value to match type.

Comment: @EricV. How did it go? Did the updated answer worked?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. This worked following the updated value. Thank you a million.